# ASP.NET Unicode string displays incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, unicode, iis-7.5

I have the image:

```
http://localhost/WOZNIAK.png
```

This comes out fine. However, if I URL rewrite this with this rule:

```
<rewrite url="~/images/articles/(.*)$" to="~/handlers/displayimage.ashx?src=$1&amp;type=article" processing="stop"/>
```

And visit this URL:

```
http://localhost/images/articles/WOZNIAK.png
```

It doesn't show the image. My handler starts with the code:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string ImageSrc = context.Request.QueryString["src"];
    string ImageType = context.Request.QueryString["type"];
```

And if I take the `ImageSrc` value it outputs as:

```
WOÅ¹NIAK.png
```

If I explicitly set `ImageSrc` to be the value `ImageSrc = "WOZNIAK.png";` in the code the image display fine.

What do I need to do to allow these Unicode characters to pass properly? It's very problematic for us as we have users all over the world uploading large sets of images, some of which contain a lot of names with Unicode characters.

Renaming or modifying these images in any way is very problematic due to design, so I would really like a solution to this problem!

**Edit**

It appears I should probably `Server.UrlEncode` all query string params. Could this be the cause? I'm not sure if it's possible to do that in the URL rewrite rule though?

If I set the string to:

```
ImageSrc = context.Server.UrlDecode("WO%c5%b9NIAK.png");
```

It works. So I suppose the problem is URL encoding the querystring param in the rewrite rule.

Comment: I think encoding query string then decoding it will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. Intelligencia has the URL encode transform which can be used like in the following:

```
<rewrite url="~/images/articles/(.*)$" to="~/handlers/displayimage.ashx?src=${encode($1)}&amp;type=article" processing="stop"/>
```

Then display the image as follows in the code:

```
string ImageSrc = context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString["src"]);
```